# JRMI specification

Tags: java, server, rmi

In my understanding java.rmi is a specification.
How do I know what particular implementation of java.rmi am I using when I'm developing using that API.

Also is there a limit on the maximum number of threads that
are started on an RMI server ?

Comment: In contrast to the XML API, where there are at least two well known Java SPI service providers, RMI is built-in. With remote-method-invokation you are writing client and server yourself. One instance means one port, one socket. No high-struck architecture.

Answer (score 1):

You use the implementation by the provider of the JDK. Therm isn't a provider architecture like there is in JNDI, NIO, JCA, etc.

The RMI Specification doesn't mention any limit on threads.

Answer (score -1):

I would hardly call RMI a "specification".  It is a quite Java specific serialization implementation; and it's whatever implementation matches the JRE version you are running.  I would advise not randomly mixing and matching JRE versions between client and server when RMI is in use.  Nor would I advise serializing POJOs using exotic features that don't exist in older VMs.

Though it's not "specified", I have reverse engineered an almost complete RMI implementation for C# before (for use with Spring/Hibernate based servers from WPF), but I don't know of anybody that uses such non JRE implementations in the real world.  You get stuck with RMI just to communicate with J2EE systems in some cases.  But, if at all possible, you should use something more reasonable like ProtocolBuffers/Thrift/Avro/Hessian/Parqet, etc.  Those have real "specifications" with a versioned wire protocol and IDL compilers for multiple platforms; which was absolutely not the case at the time I did that for RMI.

RMI has other problems that I would categorize as security issues (ie: you spell out a class name in the serialization stream and it will call a no-arg constructor to create a class of that name).  Its design also isn't very good for situations where object graphs can get large.  (In particular, you can make the stack grow really large during deserialization.)

Comment: You've stated twice that's it isn't specified. I wonder what the RMI Specification is all about then. All of your objections really concern serialization rather than RMI, and they're not all accurate.

Comment: I stand corrected.  It's somewhat documented (somewhat recently).  At the time I had to make a C# client, it was definitely just whatever happened to work with the current VM.  It still isn't a protocol with a version independent of the VM, which is better than nothing.

Comment: I have a JRMP specification from JDK 1.1.8, which was released in 1999. It's the same as the specification in new Java 8 releases.

Comment: Yes, I know that there is a document.  But when you go to actually implement it for yourself, you find out why nothing but Java implements it.  It's not really a spec, like an RFC.  You are in C#, and you are asked to deserialize java.util.Hashtable.  It is expected that shooting code around between machines is reasonable, that the pojos java similar code attached, etc.  Is it ok for the C# classes to have totally different methods?  A real protocol specification lays out an unambiguous grammar of immutable structs, and its version has nothing to do with the runtime, etc.

Comment: @Rob See the Protocol chapter of the Java RMI Specification, which refers to the Java Object Serialization Specification. The wire protocol is specified right down to the bit level. You're making this up.

Comment: @user207421 I implemented enough of the protocol in C# about 15 years ago to connect to JBoss.  I went and looked at the specification again; and is as underspecified what I remember.  It's not the RMI part of it that's the problem.  It's that I found myself having to reverse-engineer the fine details of object serialization from packet captures; and looking at Java source.  In particular, the way that it compresses object graphs, which is object serialization - not really RMI proper, by remembering previously seen objects is woefully underspecified.

Comment: At the time, I read some version of this

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/platform/serialization/spec/protocol.html, and the RMI paperwork.  I'm pretty sure that if you ALSO implemented the protocol, you reached a point where you had to just start referring to source code inside the JDK, and possibly looking at packet captures of network traffic.

Comment: btw... when I did this security issue at the time and nobody at Sun seemed interested: Because it looks up a class name written into the stream, you can call any zero-arg constructor on any object that implements Serializable.  With the Lua sandbox, you can specify a list of callable functions by contrast.  The caller can jump around code checks in constructors, by just writing the target object state, this way.  I have also parsed class files to produce object graphs of compiled code; and my experience with the class file format was that it involved less guesswork from what was available.

Comment: Anyways, I read my original comment, and it is totally right.  Very few languages even bother to implement Java Serialization protocol for a good reason.  The main issue is that basic data structures like maps and lists are referred to by Java class name that assumes that you have loaded Java code.  If you are writing a Go implementation, then  you need to transliterate POJO source between languages.  A sane system that is widely used across languages, like GRPC or JSON, sticks to consistently reproducing data structures between languages. Code class/struct names are not in the wire protocol.

Comment: "How do I know what particular implementation of java.rmi am I using when I'm developing using that API." -- the original question.  RMI/JavaSerialization is tied to code implementations on both sides; which is why in practice, you want clients talking with the same version of application code.  I was careful about using serial version id.  You should also have in a POJO, a version number that specifies the library version in use by both sides.